# What could happen when I register signal handlers for previously ignored signals

Tags: c, signals

The following code is from an example in the [GNU manual about signal handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html)

```
...
if (signal(SIGINT, termination_handler) == SIG_IGN)
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
...
```

The manual says,

> Note that if a given signal was previously set to be ignored, this code avoids altering that setting. This is because non-job-control shells often ignore certain signals when starting children, and it is important for the children to respect this.

I don't understand why ignored signals should be kept as ignored when non-job-control shells make some signals ignored before starting my process. (What does it mean by "non-job-control shells"?)

I found a similar part in my book, 'The Linux System Programming' written by Robert Love. The book says,

> When a process is first executed, all signals are set to their default actions, unless the parent process (the one executing the new process) is ignoring them; in this case, the newly created process will also ignore those signals. Put another way, any signal caught by the parent is reset to the default action in the new process, and all other signals remain the same. This makes sense because a freshly executed process does not share the address space of its parent, and thus any registered signal handlers may not exist.
>
> This behavior on process execution has one notable use: when the shell executes a process "in the background" (or when another background process executes another process), the newly executed process should ignore the interrupt and quit characters.
>
> Thus, before a shell executes a background process, it should set SIGINT and SIGQUIT to SIG_IGN. It is therefore common for programs that handle these signals to first check to make sure they are not ignored.

I tried registering a signal handler for SIGINT (without checking ignored or not) and running it in the background (just to see what happens if I do what they're saying not to do).

```
$ ./my_program &
```

But nothing special happened.

What could be happen when I register signal handlers for previously ignored signals?

Comment: How did you arrange for signals to be sent to your backgrounded process?

Comment: Notice that *your* shell most probably *is a job control shell*.

Comment: I didn't send any signal to my process. I registered a handler for SIG_INT. I know SIG_INT is occured by Ctrl+C and there will be no way to occure SIG_INT in background. So I want to know why SIG_INT should be kept as ignored (if SIG_INT does not occur in background process) And I want to know what goes wrong if I send SIG_INT to my background process by kill command.

Comment: Classically, signals sent to/by the terminal are sent to all processes with that terminal as a controlling terminal. When you run a process in background, if your background process hasn't daemonized itself (detached from the controlling terminal, for example), then it will receive interrupts.  If your shell set your signal mask to ignore interrupts, it would be a pity to reenable them and have your process die when the shell had taken steps to ensure it didn't.  I'm not sure of the ramifications of job control shells on all this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe a job control shell will use the process groups to change whatever job is connected to the terminal http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_78.html#SEC85 using tcsetpgrp

Comment: I believe I know how to answer this question but I don't have time to do it now. Anyway, your shell *is* a job-control shell, so none of this applies (try printing in your program if the signal was ignored)

Comment: Thank you for comments. Um... but my question is why I should NOT register a signal handler when the shell makes some signal ignored. Jonathan Leffler said it is a pity idea and I agree. But checking the signal is ignored needs more code and I believe there should be a reason to more code.

Comment: I used to use a non-job-control shell around 15 years ago on some systems. It set backgrounded processes to ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT. If the shell didn't do this, or if the background process decided to register handlers or set the signal disposition to SIG_DFL despite the signals being ignored, then any time I typed ^C to the shell, that background process would exit. There were a few programs that did this.

Comment: Does "K&R showed that's how you do it" count as a good reason? With `sigaction()`, you can get the current value without changing anything; with `signal()`, you have to set a signal handler, but the classic technique sets it to SIG_IGN and checks whether it was already SIG_IGN before setting it to something active. IOW, the classic code would be `if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN) signal(SIGINT, termination_handler);` because it doesn't leave a window of vulnerability during which signals might be delivered when you didn't want them delivered.

Comment: Whatever the gnu "solution" imply a problem because it's change the sighandler for a period of time, so this is not a good solution. You could receive the signal when it's not ignored. Use `sigaction` to do this correctly, `signal()` is broken.